# Change first element from SVG/XML

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I have a svg files starting for example with :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<!-- Généré par Microsoft Visio 11.0, SVG Export, v1.0 A_QI_QCompliance_ICompliance_AAfr.svg Compliance -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
        xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" width="11.6872in" height="8.79076in"
        viewBox="0 0 841.476 632.935" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st36">
```

Using javascript, I want to change the first line :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

into :

```
<?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" type="text/css" href="../../style/css/customSVG.css"?>
```

I can't figure out how to access this element/node to change his tagname/attributes.

The `firstChild`is the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` tag and the `documentElement` is the `<svg>...</svg>` tag

I can't create an element of type xml or ?xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodeDoctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType(
 'xml',
 'xml-stylesheet version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" type="text/css" href="../../style/css/customSVG.css'
);
if(document.doctype) {
    document.replaceChild(nodeDoctype, document.doctype);
} else {
    document.insertBefore(nodeDoctype, document.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Update based on your comment:

It is possible to change the doctype with JS to enable compatability viewing (as done here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4856.htm) but is quite a nasty hack and not recommended. Ideally you can do this server side. So have a doctype js parameter and then do a page reload:

```
window.location = window.location+"?doctype=newdoctype"
```

This will cause the page to reload which might not suit you, but is the safest way to do it.

Comment: It seems there is one attribute missing in the createDocumentType function.
And isnt it to change the <doctype> tag, instead of the <?xml> ?